# Click function never reading else statement to remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, click

I have been stuck on a sliding down menu, but have made some headway with it. I had to modify a lot to make it work for both desktop and mobile viewports. The only thing I am stuck on now is getting the menu to close in a < 640px viewport. 
In my snippet and jsfiddle below there is a lot of code, but the only code that really matters to this question is the javascript below:

```
$('#serviceClick').click( function () {
    var relative = $(this);
    if (!relative.hasClass('activeSol')) {
        $('#serviceNav').removeClass('activeSol');
        $('#serviceNav').addClass('activeSol').slideDown();
    } else  {
        $('#serviceNav').removeClass('activeSol').slideUp(500);
    }
    return false;
});
```

Basically my else statement is now removing the class 'activeSol` and then sliding up the selection.

In the mobile viewport, after clicking on "Solutions" the menu expands, but when you click on "Solutions" again, nothing happens.

[image]

It seems as if the variable `relative` is never reading as the class appended to it, making the click function run `else`. I did a simple `console.log` and the else never runs. I tried changing the `click` function to a `change`, but then the menu never triggers.

Does anyone see what is causing my else statement to not `removeClass` from `serviceNav` and `slideUp`?

[JSfiddle link to see in mobile viewport.](https://jsfiddle.net/nfdkyxuf/3/)

```js
$('#serviceClick').click( function () {
  var relative = $(this);
  if (!relative.hasClass('activeSol')) {
   $('#serviceNav').removeClass('activeSol');
   $('#serviceNav').addClass('activeSol').slideDown();
  } else  {
   $('#serviceNav').removeClass('activeSol').slideUp(500);
  }
  return false;
 });
 $('[data-pop-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
  //var targeted_pop = $(this).attr('data-pop-close');
  $('#serviceNav').removeClass('activeSol');
  $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
  e.preventDefault();
 });
```

```css
nav {
 background: #FFF;
 height: 70px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 box-shadow: 0px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 999;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#nav-logo {
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 5%;
}
#nav-logo img {
 height: 80%;
 width: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#mobile-button {
 background-image: url("https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mbkitsystems/menu.svg");
    background-size: 30px 30px;
 float: right;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-right: 5%;
 margin-top: 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: none;
 transition: ease 0.3s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.3s;
}
#mobile-button:hover {
 transition: ease 0.3s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.3s;
}
#nav-pop {
 float: right;
 display: block;
 margin-right: 5%;
 margin-top: 25px;
 transition: ease 0.5s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.5s;
}
#nav-pop.active {
 opacity: 1;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 background: #2f2f2f;
 right: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 z-index: 999999;
 transition: ease 0.6s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.6s;
 transform: translateX(0);-webkit-transform: translateX(0);
 box-shadow: -9px 0px 9px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
#nav-list li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 17px;
 vertical-align: top;
}
#nav-list li:first-child {
 margin-left: 0px;
}
#nav-list li:last-child {
 margin-right: 0px;
}
#nav-list li a, #serviceClick {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
 font-size: .9rem;
 color: #747678;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 vertical-align: top;
 transition: all .3s;-webkit-transition: all .3s;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#nav-list li a:after, #serviceClick:after {
 content: '';
    display: block;
 width: 0;
 margin-top: 6px;
 background: #b82222;
 height: 2px;
 transition: width .3s;
}
#nav-list li a:hover, #serviceClick:hover {
 color: #4b4b4b;
 transition: all .3s;-webkit-transition: all .3s;
}
#nav-list li a:hover:after, #serviceClick:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    transition: width .3s;
}
#nav-list li a.navInverse {
 padding: 10px 12px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 color: #FFF;
 border: 1px solid #b82222;
 background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #b82222, #a51e1e);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#nav-list li a.navInverse:hover {
 background: #b82222;
 background: #FFF;
 color: #b82222;
 /*transition: all 0s;-webkit-transition: all 0s;*/
}
#nav-list li a.navInverse:after {
 content: '';
    display: none;
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
 transition: none;
}
#nav-pop-close {
 display: none;
}
#nav-pop-close, #close-panel {
 position: relative;
 top: 3%;
 left: 90%;
 background-image: url("https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mbkitsystems/icon_close.png");
 background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
/*- Service NAV -*/
#serviceNav {
    width: 100%;
    top: -40vh;
 left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    height: 40vh;
    transition: all .4s;
 padding: 20px 0;
}
#serviceNav.activeSol {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
    z-index: 99999;
 height: 40vh;
}
.popup-close {
 position: absolute;
 right: 12px;
 top: 12px;
 width: 32px;
 height: auto;
}
#serviceNavInner {
 margin: 0 5%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
/*--- Block 1 ---*/
#serviceNavBlock1 {
 width: 33%;
 height: 100%;
 border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
 position: relative;
}
#serviceNavBlock1Wrap {
 width: 80%; 
 text-align: left;
}
/*--- Block 2 ---*/
#serviceNavBlock2 {
 width: 66.6%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 10px auto;
 position: relative;
}
.servNavItemWrap {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 25%;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.servNavItemWrap img {
 width: 75px;
 height: 75px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;transition: all 0.25s;
}
.servNavItemWrap:hover img {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;transition: all 0.25s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);transform: scale(1.1);
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.servNavItemWrap a {
 text-decoration: none;
 outline: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.servNavItemTitle {
 margin-top: 5px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;transition: all 0.25s;
}
.servNavItemWrap:hover .servNavItemTitle {
 color: #FFF;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;transition: all 0.25s;
}

/*---------------------------------------------- MEDIA QUERY 640 --------------------------------------------*/

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
  
  #mobile-button {
 display: block;
}
#nav-pop {
 float: none;
 opacity: 0;
 position: fixed;
 margin-top: 0;
 width: 75%;
 right: -100%;
 height: 100vh;
 transform: translateX(100%);-webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
}
#nav-pop-close {
 display: block;
 background-size: 20px 20px;
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
}
#nav-list {
 margin-top: 20px;
}
#nav-list li {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 20px 10%;
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #151515, #2f2f2f);
 background: #2f2f2f;
 text-align: left;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-bottom: .3px solid #FFF;
}
#quoteButton {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}
#nav-list li:hover #quoteButton {
 background: #2f2f2f;
}
#nav-list li:hover, #nav-list li:active {
 background: #000;
}
#nav-list li:first-child {
 margin-left: 0;
}
#nav-list li:last-child {
 margin: 20px auto;
 text-align: center;
 border-bottom: none;
 background: #2f2f2f;
 padding: 20px 0;
}
#nav-list li a, #serviceClick {
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 font-size: .8rem;
 color: #FFF;
 letter-spacing: .3rem;
}
#nav-list li a:after, #serviceClick:after {
    display: none;
}
#nav-list li a:hover, #serviceClick:hover {
 color: #FFF;
}
#nav-list li a:hover:after, #serviceClick:hover:after {
    width: 0%;
}
/*- Service NAV -*/
#serviceNav {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    height: 200px;
    transition: all .4s;
 padding: 10px 0;
 display: none;
 top: 0;
}
#serviceNav.activeSol {
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 9999999;
 height: auto;
 min-height: 20%;
 top: 0;
 border-bottom: .01em solid #FFF;
}
.popup-close {
 display: none;
}
#serviceNavInner {
 margin: 0 2.5%;
}
/*--- Block 1 ---*/
#serviceNavBlock1 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 border-right: none;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}
#serviceNavBlock1Wrap {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
#navOverviewT, #navOverviewP {
 display: none;
}
#solOverviewB {
 font-size: .7rem;
}
/*--- Block 2 ---*/
#serviceNavBlock2 { 
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 10px auto;
 display: block;
}
.servNavItemWrap {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 25%;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.servNavItemWrap img {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
}
.servNavItemTitle {
 margin-top: 5px;
 font-size: .5rem;
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
 <div id="nav-logo">
 </div>
 <div id="mobile-button"><img src="" class="hidden" alt=""></div>
 <div id="nav-pop">
 <div id="nav-pop-close"></div>
  <ul id="nav-list">
   <li><a href="http://localhost:8080/about.php">ABOUT</a></li>
   <li id="serviceClick">SOLUTIONS</li>
   <div id="serviceNav">
    <div id="serviceNavInner">
     <div id="serviceNavBlock1" class="iblock">
       <a href="http://localhost:8080/solutions.php"><button class="buttonInv2" id="solOverviewB">Solutions Overview</button></a>
     </div><div id="serviceNavBlock2" class="iblock">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <li><a href="http://localhost:8080/learn.php">LEARN</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://localhost:8080/contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://localhost:8080/quote.php" class="navInverse" id="quoteButton">REQUEST QUOTE</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var relative = $(this);`
Is picking the `serviceClick` list item (li) and then you are checking

```
    if (!relative.hasClass('activeSol')) {
```

but you never added the class to the li, instead you added it to the div `#serviceNav`.

I think changing

`if (!relative.hasClass('activeSol')) {`

to

`if (!$('#serviceNav').hasClass('activeSol')) {`

should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your shouldn't check for `$("#serviceClick")` for class `activeSol`, should check on `$("#serviceNav")` instead.

```
if (!$('#serviceNav').hasClass('activeSol')) {
    $('#serviceNav').removeClass('activeSol');
    $('#serviceNav').addClass('activeSol').slideDown();
} else  { 
    $('#serviceNav').removeClass('activeSol').slideUp(500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`relative` doesn't have the class `'activeSol'` and will never have it, in order to have it toggle the visibility of your menu, you should add and remove classes to it, like this:

```
$('#serviceClick').click( function () {
  var relative = $(this);
  if (!relative.hasClass('opened')) { // if it's not opened
    relative.addClass('opened');   // open it
    $('#serviceNav').removeClass('activeSol');
    $('#serviceNav').addClass('activeSol').slideDown();
  } else  { // if it's opened
    relative.removeClass('opened');  // close it
    $('#serviceNav').removeClass('activeSol').slideUp(500);
  }
  return false;
});
```